# Find a homeomorphism of the sphere with itself

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, general-topology, group-theory

Question: Let $x$ and $y$ be points on the sphere. Find a homeomorphism of the sphere with itself which takes $x$ to $y$.

Solution:
The special orthogonal group $SO(n)$ are rotations of $n$ space given by square $n × n$ matrices $M$ with $det(M) = 1$ and $MM^T = I$.

These are length (and angle) preserving transformations. An orthogonal matrix therefore takes the unit sphere to itself.

The columns are orthogonal unit vectors. Let $x$ be any point on the unit sphere. Extend $\{x\}$ to an orthonormal basis and make a matrix $R$ from these vectors with $x$ as the first column.

Then this matrix takes the first standard basis vector $e_1$ to $x$.

Likewise there is an orthogonal matrix $S$ that takes $e_1$ to $y$. Then $SR^{−1}$ is a transformation that takes $x$ to $y$.

Linear transformations are continuous. Things in $SO(n)$ are invertible, so give homeomorphisms.

---

Can anyone if its possible help me break down this solution (*or parts of it*) in pieces that are easier to understand with a little less advanced group theory, linear algebra etc or more intuitive arguments? I am working hard on rehearsing my group theory and linear algebra but i am still far from understanding a solution like this. Thanks.

---

edit: This is what is left for me to understand. The rest i think i got know. 
My linear algebra is not good at all.

Extend $\{x\}$ to an orthonormal basis and make a matrix $R$ from these vectors with $x$ as the first column.

Then this matrix takes the first standard basis vector $e_1$ to $x$.

Likewise there is an orthogonal matrix $S$ that takes $e_1$ to $y$. Then $SR^{−1}$ is a transformation that takes $x$ to $y$.

Comment: Could you point out the first point you don't understand?

Comment: Yes, there is a lot in there, so it would help to know what is confusing, but also we don't know how much linear algebra you know, for example. An answerer could waste a lot of time explaining stuff you understand, or explaining stuff you don't understand using math you don't know yet. Help us help you.

Comment: @Michael Albanese . After reading Justpassingsby's answer, which was very good, and spending an hour googling im mostly struggling with this part:                                                                                   $$*$$Extend $\{x\}$ to an orthonormal basis and make a matrix $R$ from these vectors with $x$ as the first column. 

$$*$$Then this matrix takes the first standard basis vector $e_1$ to $x$. 

$$*$$ Likewise there is an orthogonal matrix $S$ that takes $e_1$ to $y$. Then $SR^{−1}$ is a transformation that takes $x$ to $y$.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews I took my linear algebra course 14 years ago so you could expect i have forgotten a lot.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews That im struggling with this part despite justpassingby's answer and that i think i understand most of his answer probably shows about how much linear algebra i know?

Comment: Sure, but that means in order to figure out how to answer you, a reader has to read your comments, read a first answer, and read your question. Your question should be a self-contained entity, and the more time you require people to invest, the less likely they are to help you. @JKnecht

Comment: @Thomas Andrews True, i forgot i could edit the original post. Thx.

Comment: Choose a co-ordinate system in which x and y are on the equator. Rotate  the sphere about the N-S axis until x reaches y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find *any* rotation of $n$-dimensional space that maps $x$ to $y.$ The whole group theoretic machinery is just to ensure the existence of such a rotation. You can get around it with an explicit construction.

Consider the 2-dimensional subspace $P$ (of $n$-dimensional space) that is spanned by $x$ and $y.$ In this 2-dimensional subspace $x$ can be mapped to $y$ by a rotation $\rho$ in the plane (over an angle $\theta$ with $\cos\theta=x.y$).

We extend this planar rotation to an $n$-dimensional rotation $R$ as follows. For any $n$-vector $x$ consider its orthogonal projection $\pi x$ on $P.$ Define $Rx=\rho(\pi x)+(x-\pi x),$ in other words: apply $\rho$ to the component of $x$ parallel to $P,$ and leave the component of $x$ perpendicular to $P$ alone.

It is not difficult to see that $R$ maps the unit sphere to itself. Since $\rho(\pi x)$ is still inside $P,$ it is perpendicular to $x-\pi x$ and therefore Pythagoras applies:

$$\eqalign{
\|Rx\|^2
&=\|\rho(\pi x)+x-\pi x\|^2 \\
&=\|\rho(\pi x)\|^2+\|x-\pi x\|^2\hbox{ (Pythagoras)} \\
&=\|\pi x\|^2+\|x-\pi x\|^2\hbox{ (planar rotations preserve length)} \\
&=\|\pi x+x-\pi x\|^2\hbox{ (Pythagoras)} \\
&=\|x\|^2
}$$

The fact that $R$ is one-to-one and onto can be verified by realising that its inverse can be defined in exactly the same way with the sign of the angle $\theta$ reversed.

Continuity can be verified directly with the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition by considering the components of each vector parallel and perpendicular to $P$ separately.

Comment: Thx! I think i understand most of your very good answer.  And i understand it as a solution to the question but im still a little lost regarding the things in my comments above. The rest of the solution i think i got now.

Comment: The "complicated" solution that you quote in your problem statement actually leaves a lot of freedom on how to extend $x$ to a basis of $n$-space. My construction restricts the choices: the second basis vector must lie in the same plane as $x$ and $y,$ and the other $n-2$ basis vectors are perpendicular to the first two. My rotation, viewed as an example of the linear transformation $SR^{-1},$ has a matrix that is identical to the unit matrix except in the upper left corner (four entries) where it has $\cos\theta, \sin\theta, -\sin\theta, \cos\theta.$